# How to measure the Speed between two Waypoints?

Tags: qgis, distance

I'm totally new to QGIS or any GIS.

I need to analyze a lot of Waypoints to get the average speed of the people walking between them. (It's for analyzing an experiment I made) therefore I neet do measure the **Distance** and the **speed** between the waypoints I got.

I have a lot of csv tables with the geografic dates and the time of each waypoint. I imported them in QGIS and now I've got them as a shape layer.

Now I have two methods, one is to take the speed from the first, the middle and the last and make an average time based on a measurement I made, it's ok but maybe it's better to do the second one:

I neet to measure the DISTANCE between the waypoints and then to get the speed based on the time and the distance. In the end I can calculate the average speed out of the "Speeds" I got. 
I think this is a job for the Field Calculator, but I don't know how to do this, can you help me?

Comment: Are you able to write/use a script, or do you need a solution that only uses the QGIS graphic interface?

Comment: sorry guys, I'm not really able to write a script :) thanks Edison, I'll try your program! but after some more discussions and reflections I think I will take the "shortcut method" because it's fairly more precise. I'll measure the distance of the "real path" the people walked and take just the start and the endpoints like a stopwatch and then calculate the speed. Mostly because the GPS Waypoints are pretty scattered around the pathway... but the other method would show me if the people had some differences in the speed on their way, so it's worth having an eye on it. thanks

Comment: It looks like you created a new account instead of logging into your existing one. You should [merge the two](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). When you are using the correct account you'll be able to edit and comment on your question/answers.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/78634)